# Selecting multiple second instances of a queryselectorAll element?

Tags: javascript, chartist.js

I am using Chartist and I need to send some data to the repeated second occurrence of an element. For example, there are two "ct-bar" elements inside every "ct-series" element. I need to select the second "ct-bar" element that is contained in each of the "ct-series" elements. I have tried doing this with a for loop and some other ways to no avail. How can I achieve this?

JS

```
const series = xChart.querySelectorAll('.ct-series .ct-bar')
for (var i = 0; i < series.length; i++) {
                        this.element = series[i];
                        var seriesNext = series[1]
                    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `:nth-child(2)` css selector to just grab the 2nd `ct-bar` child under each `ct-series`. See below for how this would work.

```js
const series = document.querySelectorAll('.ct-series > .ct-bar:nth-child(2)')
for (var i = 0; i < series.length; i++) {
  console.log(series[i].textContent);
}
```

```html
<div class="ct-series">
  <span class="ct-bar">foo 1</span>
  <span class="ct-bar">bar 1</span>
</div>
<div class="ct-series">
  <span class="ct-bar">foo 2</span>
  <span class="ct-bar">bar 2</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `:nth-child()` selector to get the 2nd child of each series.

```
const bars = xChart.querySelectorAll('.ct-series > .ct-bar:nth-child(2)');
```